# What is the algorithm for "vibrance" filters?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors

Many applications have a vibrance filter that increases saturation of the colors other than skin tone.  I'd like to know what algorithm is behind this filter -- is there a source that can be pointed out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on whether it's "positive vibrance" or "negative vibrance". Negative vibrance may be just desaturation (or maybe not, or it may depend on the implementation). Positive vibrance increases the saturation of colours, but it increases it more for colours that were less saturated to begin with, and it has something special going on if the red component is the biggest component. Looking at an implementation, this is roughly what's going on: (I don't guarantee that it corresponds to what you define as Vibrance though, it's a fairly mysterious thing)

```
x = max(r, g, b)
y = min(r, g, b)
gray = toGray(unGamma(r, g, b))
scale = input
if x == r:
    t = min(1, abs((g - b) / (x - y)))
    scale = scale * (1 + t) * 0.5
a = (x - y) / 255
scale1 = scale * (2 - a)
scale2 = 1 + scale1 * (1 - a)
sub = y * scale1
r = unGamma(r * scale2 - sub)
g = unGamma(g * scale2 - sub)
b = unGamma(b * scale2 - sub)
gray2 = toGray(r, g, b)
r *= gray / gray2
g *= gray / gray2
b *= gray / gray2
m = max(r, g, b)
if Gamma(m) > 255:
    scale = (unGamma(255) - gray2) / (m - gray2)
    r = (r - gray2) * scale + gray2
    g = (g - gray2) * scale + gray2
    b = (b - gray2) * scale + gray2
(r, g, b) = Gamma(r, g, b)
```

More or less. I don't have anything to point to except implementations, it seem that no one wants to talk about it.

Comment: Do you have a commented version (like, what exactly does unGamma do) or a source with more information?

Comment: @AllanLRH `unGamma` converts colours to linear space, the opposite of `Gamma` (this is gamma as in "gamma-correction", it depends on the colour space that the image is in and typically both functions are some lookup table). I don't really have a proper source of information, the only way I could even get this much is by decompiling code that implements it

Comment: Very strange code. Why, for example, does it use special treatment for colors with the dominating red primary, or why does it mix computations in linear and gamma-corrected RGB? Both look to me like hackish and arbitrary design decisions due to lack of a good and consistent measure of saturation. Thanks for taking the trouble of decompiling, Harold.

Comment: @harold `scale2` is uninitialised—did you make a typo?

Comment: Special handling of the dominating red may be required not to ruin skin tones. I have deleted my answer, but will post a better one as time permits. Sorry.

Comment: @Ant_222 OK it turns out it was `scale1` instead of `scale2` there

Comment: @harold Since I have discovered a similar method, I believe I can add comments this code as well. Can you please check it for other typos?

Comment: Negative vibrance does not seem to just be desaturation. While -100 saturation does indeed fully desaturate the image, -100 vibrance persists some color. And it doesn't seem to just be desaturation with a slowing multiplier, the color is actually different. But this post's main algorithm definitely does not work in the negative direction, so I have no idea what to use for negative vibrance.